# Python threads passing parameters

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to passing some parameter to the server tread, but I have no idea how?

this is my code:

```
HOST, PORT = socket.gethostbyname( socket.gethostname() ), 31000
self.server = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer( ( HOST, PORT ), MCRequestHandler )
ip, port = self.server.server_address        
self.server_thread = threading.Thread( target = self.server.serve_forever )
```

this is the MCRequestHandler

```
class MCRequestHandler( SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler ):

    global Lidars, clientsLock, postbox
    Lidars = []
    postbox = {}
    clientsLock = threading.RLock()    

    def setup( self ):
        clientsLock.acquire()
```

How can I pass one or two parameter to the MCRequestHandler class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the second parameter of ThreadingTCPServer is a factory:

```
  SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer( ( HOST, PORT ), MCRequestHandler )
```

What you could do is your own factory here. Class will contstuct a callable object. when the object is called it will initialize MCRequestHandler with parameters given to the factory:

```
class MyRequestHandlerFactory(object):

  def __init__(self, param1, param2): 
            self.param1 = param1
            self.param2 = param2

  def __call__(self):
            handler = MCRequestHandler()
            handler.param1 = param1
            handler.param2 = param2
```

Then initialize:

```
  factory = MyRequestHandlerFactory("x", "y")
  SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer( ( HOST, PORT ), factory)
```

Comment: I did this, but get this error. TypeError: __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given. Does anyone know what could be the reason?

Comment: @bronco: try this signature `def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)` and pass the args to the handler transparently: `YourRequestHandler(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: If I do that I get ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: @broncoAbierto: add `return handler` to the `__call__`.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian Still complaining about the arg count (takes 3, 4 given). I find threading in this ServerSocket framework a little weird. I'm gonna go with Twisted, I think.